# code with thread crashes at startup (android beginner)

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an application that passes through the audio samples obtained at the microphone to the speaker. This is the source code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    AudioManager am = null;
    AudioRecord record =null;
    AudioTrack track =null;
    final int SAMPLE_FREQUENCY = 44100;
    final int SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY = 1024;
    boolean isPlaying = false;
    class MyThread extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run(){
            recordAndPlay();
        }
    }

    MyThread newThread;

    private void init() {
        int min = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        record = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION, SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                                 AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, min);
        int maxJitter = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION, SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                               AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, maxJitter, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
     }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        init();
        newThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void recordAndPlay() {
        short[] lin = new short[SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY];
        int num = 0;
        am = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
        record.startRecording();
        track.play();
        while (true) {
            num = record.read(lin, 0, SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY);
            track.write(lin, 0, num);
        }
    }

    public void passStop(View view){
        Button playBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playBtn);  
        // /*
        if(!isPlaying){
            record.startRecording();
            track.play();
            isPlaying = true;
            playBtn.setText("Pause");
        }
        if(isPlaying){
           record.stop();
           track.pause();
           isPlaying=false;
           playBtn.setText("Pass through");
        }
        // */
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        newThread.stop();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this program stops as soon as I try to run it through eclipse. This is wht I get in the logcat but I am not sure what it all means:

```
08-19 18:58:43.365: D/AndroidRuntime(27915): Shutting down VM
08-19 18:58:43.365: W/dalvikvm(27915): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4161f700)
08-19 18:58:43.365: E/AndroidRuntime(27915): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 18:58:43.365: E/AndroidRuntime(27915): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mypassthrough/com.example.mypassthrough.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-19 18:58:43.365: E/AndroidRuntime(27915):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
08-19 18:58:43.365: E/AndroidRuntime(27915):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-19 18:58:43.365: E/AndroidRuntime(27915):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-19 18:58:43.365: E/AndroidRuntime(27915):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-19 18:58:43.365: E/AndroidRuntime(27915):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-19 18:58:43.365: E/AndroidRuntime(27915):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-19 18:58:43.365: E/AndroidRuntime(27915):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-19 18:58:43.365: E/AndroidRuntime(27915):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 18:58:43.365: E/AndroidRuntime(27915):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-19 18:58:43.365: E/AndroidRuntime(27915):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-19 18:58:43.365: E/AndroidRuntime(27915):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-19 18:58:43.365: E/AndroidRuntime(27915):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-19 18:58:43.365: E/AndroidRuntime(27915): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-19 18:58:43.365: E/AndroidRuntime(27915):    at com.example.mypassthrough.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
08-19 18:58:43.365: E/AndroidRuntime(27915):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-19 18:58:43.365: E/AndroidRuntime(27915):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-19 18:58:43.365: E/AndroidRuntime(27915):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
08-19 18:58:43.365: E/AndroidRuntime(27915):    ... 11 more
```

What could be the reason for this code crashing, and how can it be debugged? I am pretty sure it has something to do with `Thread`, because my other versions of this code where I have not included Thread at all do not crash on startup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable newThread is not initialized in `oncreate()` `method` that's why it is giving `nullpointer` `exception`

add this in your init() method it will work

```
newThread=new Thread();
```

Comment: nice catch. thanks a lot. But now after adding `newThread=new Thread();`, it is crashing when I end the application, probably in `onDestroy()`

Comment: what exception is comingt here??

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a null pointer exception because newThread has not been initialized yet and it is null when you try to start it. The thread doesn't have anything to do also. You should look at implementing a runnable, handler, and timer into your activity instead of a thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use sub class with extending AsyncTask Class

```
class TestActivity extends AsyncTask <String, Void, String > {
  protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    // execution
  }
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // post execution
  }
  protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    // initial activities
  }
}
```